# error: class ‘Software’ does not have any field named ‘ptr’

Tags: c++

I am getting the following errors:

```
softwarew.hh: In constructor ‘Software::Software(std::string, int)’:
softwarew.hh:26:45: error: class ‘Software’ does not have any field named ‘ptr’
softwarew.hh:28:7: error: ‘ptr’ was not declared in this scope
softwarew.hh: In destructor ‘Software::~Software()’:
softwarew.hh:40:6: error: ‘ptr’ was not declared in this scope
```

Can someone explain why I receive these errors?

The code that causes the errors:

```
Software(std::string name, int revision) : ptr(software_construct(name.c_str(), revision) ) {

    if(!ptr) throw std::runtime_error("no software created");
}

~Software(){
    if(ptr)
        software_destruct(ptr);
}

private: 
struct Software_s* ptr;
```

Comment: What is `Software_s`?

Comment: Are those the *only* errors or warnings?  Can you post a complete, minimal, compilable example?

Comment: Easy - it happens because "class `Software` does not have any field named `ptr`"

Comment: Post more code. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Try to put the private part and eclaration of ptr variable at the beginning of the class, i.e. before the constructor and destructor.

Comment: @RobinRobinovic That is not the issue

Comment: Are those the only errors you get? Is that *all* the code you have in the header?

Comment: I moved all implementations away from the header file, which solved the problem.
@RobinRobinovic I guess your suggestion would also have solved the problem.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore the field name was declared in the end which seemed to cause the problem

Comment: @Spacy I wonder what your header really looked like. It's not clear from your question what the problem really was.

Comment: @Spacy That's not true, it's completely normal to do what you did, it should have worked. The error was something else, but I guess you'll never find out what now, and there's a fair chance you now have a misunderstanding about C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error says

> "class Software does not have any field named ptr"

Given some suitable definitions of `Software_s`, `software_construct`, and `software_destruct`, making sure you put the field inside the class works:

```
#ifndef SOFTWAREw_INCLUDED
#defINE SOFTWAREw_INCLUDED

class Software{
  Software(std::string name, int revision)
  : ptr(software_construct(name.c_str(), revision)) {
    if(!ptr)
      throw std::runtime_error("no software created");
  }

  ~Software(){
    if(ptr)
        software_destruct(ptr);
  }

private: 
  struct Software_s* ptr;
};

#endif
```

Comment: I had the exact same layout of the code, but it still gave me the error I was having. I solved the problem by putting the declartions and implementations into different files.

Comment: @Spacy glad you solved it, but I have no idea what was really going wrong in that case.